# Previous frame seems to flicker in any type of window

Tags: unity, xorg, window, gpu-driver, flicker

Recently my 14.04 setup has run into some strange problem. Basically almost all windows  (often) start flickering the "previous frame" (or that is what it feels like). There doesn't seem to be any logic when it starts to flicker. It sometimes calms down after you leave it be for a moment. Sometimes pressing enter several times in the terminal window helps.

It affects terminal windows, GTK windows and PDF readers. Browsers seem unaffected by this, though. Some other apps are also unaffected, ie. Spotify.

I have uploaded a video of this from a terminal window, but basically the same thing happens with other type of windows as well. The video can be seen here:

[Link to youtube video showing the symptoms](http://youtu.be/U-jH6wmq1CM)

It's a fairly recent fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04, and I have NVidia GTX 560 video card. I have updated to newest drivers 337.25.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found a workaround for the problem.

In `compiz settings manager`, go to `workarounds`, and there select the checkbox for `Force full screen redraws (buffer swap) on repaint`, and it disappeared for me:

[image]

For command line (Ubuntu 14.04):

- `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
- `ccsm`
- filter on workarounds, enable workaround plugin (enable prompted dependencies)
- click on workaround plugin, check "Force full screen ..." option
- close