# Lenovo Y520 display issues

Tags: display, lenovo, youtube

I have installed ubuntu on my brand new Lenovo Y520, i am facing some major issues on display

1. All fonts looks smaller mainly on firefox and chrome
2. While playing youtube videos in high quality(720p), the video rendering as if i like 240p

Graphics : NVIDIA GETFORCE GTX
Driver using : NVIDIA 384.90 driver version

I think i have installed all drivers. What may be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: *I think i have installed all drivers* This isn't useful. What drivers? What hardware specifications, especially graphics? Please [edit] and post relevant information.

Comment: updated. if any more information, please suggest how to get the details also in ubuntu. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The steps below resolved my issues:

1. Download `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.98.run` from the Nvidia site.
2. `cd /home/your-user/Downloads`
3. `chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.98.run`
4. `./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.98.run` you might need to run as `sudo`
5. After the steps above I had some window flickering that was resolved with: [Previous frame seems to flicker in any type of window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481276/previous-frame-seems-to-flicker-in-any-type-of-window)